# Angular 2 unsubscribe - subject has no observers

Tags: angular

While implementing unsubscrive, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/7500414) answer.

I am tring the solution mentioned, but wanted to understand the following:

If I 'console.log(this.ngUnsubscribe)' before the 'this.ngUnsubscribe.next()' I see that the observers property of it is an array with 0 items.

**Does it make sense? or am I missing something?**

(before the subscribe I added the takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe) of-course)

**----Update - added the code ----**

*imports:*

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil"
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject"
```

*class:*

```
export class CarComponent{

    @Input() id;

    car:Car;

    ngUnsubscibe:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

    constructor(private carsService:CarService){}

    ngOnInit(){
       this.carsService.getDetails(this.id)
            .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscibe)
            .subscribe((car) => {this.car = car}, 
                       (err) => console.log(err)
                       );
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
         //HERE - in the log, the object has property 'observers' 
         //of type array which the length of it is 0
         console.log(this.ngUnsubscibe);
         this.ngUnsubscibe.next(true);
         this.ngUnsubscibe.complete();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you actually write `.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)`?

Comment: sure, I checked it again. any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Can you please post your actual code?

Comment: added some code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see the thing. You do not need to unsubscribe from `Observables` produced by the Angular's `http` service method calls. They automatically complete when you receive a value, because it represents an XHR call, which is obviously done by the time `ngOnDestroy` works. As it is done, the `ngUnsubscribe` `Subject` knows that the `Observable` it watches over is completed, so no need to unsubscribe it manually, thus the `ngUnsubscribe` unsubscribes from the source `Observable` to release resources. (and therefore the `observers` array becomes empty)

You only have to unsubscribe from the `Observables` that do not complete themselves. Try this code to see the difference:

```
export class CarComponent{

@Input() id;

car:Car;

ngUnsubscibe:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

constructor(private carsService:CarService){}

ngOnInit(){
   this.carsService.getDetails(this.id)
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscibe)
        .subscribe((car) => {this.car = car}, 
                   (err) => console.log(err)
                   );
    Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'click').takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
.subscribe(console.log)
     // so this is an Observable which listens to document clicks. As there 
//is no way to determine that a certain click was in fact the last, 
//we have to terminate it manually
}

ngOnDestroy(){
     //HERE - in the log, the object has property 'observers', 
     // and NOW it has length 1, as it contains the click listener Observable
     console.log(this.ngUnsubscibe);
     this.ngUnsubscibe.next(true);
     this.ngUnsubscibe.complete();
    }
}
```

So, once more - no need to unsubscribe from `http` call `Observables`, as they are automatically completed upon receiving data. A common example of `Observable` in Angular which *needs* to be terminated manually is a subscription to a form's `valueChanges` observable, any `Observables` that you wrote to transport data from one component/service to another, and maybe store `Observables` like `ngrx`  stuff, otherwise you may end up with a bunch of "zombie" `Subscriptions`, potentially resulting in a memory leak.